# How to delete the pool with state = Faulted?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux, zpool

I have a pool named test_pool and i can only see it when "zfs import" is run. How can i delete this pool and detach associated device from it ?

```
   # zpool import
       pool: test_pool
         id: 13538020891587345121
      state: FAULTED
     status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
     action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
       see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
     config:

        data_pool    FAULTED  corrupted data
          raidz1-1   ONLINE
            sdf      UNAVAIL  corrupted data
            sdg      UNAVAIL  corrupted data
            sdh      UNAVAIL  corrupted data
```

I have tried `# zpool import test_pool -f` to import and get it destroyed but get below message

```
cannot import 'data_pool': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Comment: I assumed you've tested `zpool destroy test_pool` ?

Comment: @Archemar yes i tried it but it looks like the pool should be imported first and then only it can be destroyed

Answer (score 2):

If the pool is not imported, just go ahead and wipe the data on the actual block devices. This will in essence wipe the pool.

You don't have to wipe the whole device - just the metadata is enough.

```
sudo wipefs /dev/sd{f,g,h}
```

You should see something like the below:

```
DEVICE    OFFSET      TYPE       UUID                 LABEL
sdf       0x3f000     zfs_member 13538020891587345121 ...
sdf       0x3e000     zfs_member 13538020891587345121 ...
sdf       0x3d000     zfs_member 13538020891587345121 ...
...
sdh       0x3ffa2000  zfs_member 13538020891587345121 ...
```

If you do see output with only `zfs_member` and the `UUID` to match on each line, then you got the right device - go ahead and wipe them out:

```
sudo wipefs --all --backup /dev/sd{f,g,h}
```

After that, `zpool import` should not find any pools to import.

P.S. You can use the same method to destroy any kind of device - software raid, DRBD, filesystem, etc.